# Replace contents of cell with another cell if condition on a separate cell is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have to following data frame

```
A = [1,2,5,4,3,1]
B = ["yes","No","hello","yes","no", 'why']
C = [1,0,1,1,0,0]
D = ['y','n','y','y','n','n']
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D':D})
```

we can see 4 columns A,B,C,D the intended outcome is to replace the contents of B with the contents of D, if a condition on C is met, for this example the condition is of C = 1

the intended output is

```
A = [1,2,5,4,3,1]
B = ["y","No","y","y","no", 'why']
C = [1,0,1,1,0,0]
D = ['y','n','y','y','n','n']
output_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D':D})
output_df.drop('D', axis = 1)
```

What is the best way to apply this logic to a data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve, here is another one:

```
test_df['B'] = test_df['B'].mask(test_df['C'] == 1, test_df['D'])
```

Output:

```
   A    B  C  D
0  1    y  1  y
1  2   No  0  n
2  5    y  1  y
3  4    y  1  y
4  3   no  0  n
5  1  why  0  n
```

Comment: Did not realize till today that pandas had a mask operator! Also makes the operation more readable

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `np.where`:

```
test_df['B'] = np.where(test_df['C']==1, test_df['D'], test_df['B'])
```

Output:

```
   A    B  C  D
0  1    y  1  y
1  2   No  0  n
2  5    y  1  y
3  4    y  1  y
4  3   no  0  n
5  1  why  0  n
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired output is achieved using `.loc` with column 'C' as the mask.

```
test_df.loc[test_df['C']==1,'B'] = test_df.loc[test_df['C']==1,'D']
```

UPDATE: Just found out a similar answer is posted by @QuangHoang. This answer is slightly different in that it does not require `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `inverse` is the right word here, but I noticed recently that `mask` and `where` are "inverses" of each other. If you pass a `~` to the `condition` of a `.where` statement, then you get the same result as `mask`:

```
A = [1,2,5,4,3,1]
B = ["yes","No","hello","yes","no", 'why']
C = [1,0,1,1,0,0]
D = ['y','n','y','y','n','n']
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D':D})
test_df['B'] = test_df['B'].where(~(test_df['C'] == 1), test_df['D'])
# test_df['B'] = test_df['B'].mask(test_df['C'] == 1, test_df['D']) - Scott Boston's answer
test_df
Out[1]: 
   A    B  C  D
0  1    y  1  y
1  2   No  0  n
2  5    y  1  y
3  4    y  1  y
4  3   no  0  n
5  1  why  0  n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
test_df['B'] = test_df['D'].where(test_df.C.eq(1), test_df.B)
```

Output:

```
In [875]: test_df
Out[875]: 
   A    B  C  D
0  1    y  1  y
1  2   No  0  n
2  5    y  1  y
3  4    y  1  y
4  3   no  0  n
5  1  why  0  n
```